# Where to place Magento 2 Theme customizations?

Tags: magento2, theme, css, less-css

I installed Magento 2 via Composer and it does not have a directory for theme in frontend. I tried to create a new theme in `app/design`, every time I create `registration.php` I get an error.

**Question**
Is it possible to edit the CSS file in `vendor/Magento/theme-frontend-blank`? Will the changes take in effect on front-end? 
I am confused to where should the theme customization should be done. When I use Firebug I see that the location of the CSS files are directing me to `pub/static/`

Answer (score 5):

In Magento 2, there is a term called static content deployment. You see js/css files links coming from `pub/static/` directory because Magento deploys `js/css` files to this directory from your `theme/module` directory and whenever a user visits website, static files and referred/shown from pub/static/ directory.

Initially you will be developing your frontend theme in `app/design/frontend/` and you can deploy static content to `pub/static/frontend/` using command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`. During development you should delete everything inside `pub/static/`, `var/cache/`, `var/page_cache/`, `var/generation/` and deploy you content using above command.

Here is basic theme configuration example which goes inside app/design/frontend/MyStore/MyAbstract/

**theme.xml**

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>Mystore</title>
<parent>Magento/blank</parent>
<media>
    <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
</media>
</theme>
```

**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/MyStore/MyAbstract',
    __DIR__
);
```

Put preview image preview.jpg (you can change name is theme.xml) inside media directory and you should see your theme in admin section store configuration.

Comment: i have tried several times - theme is not showing up in backend. I followed the above method, when i add registration.php - i get an error when i go to home page and the backend.

Comment: @roger: Have you enabled php error hints and developer mode to see what error you're getting?

Comment: i appreciate your help guys. Thank you. finally I was able to get it to work. I think it was my composer file causing the issue.

Comment: @roger,  Please tell me how you solved that?

Answer (score 2):

When you install magento2 via composer you find all modules and themes under the vendor dir.

if you want to customize the blank theme, you should create a new theme which is extending the blank theme. (For developing you can create your theme under app/design like in the github repository).

You need at least the registration.php and a theme.xml.

Best example for how to extend the blank theme is the luma theme: 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.0.2/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma

You also should enable the developer mode in your webroots .htaccess file (just remove the #) https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/.htaccess#L5

The developer mode ensures that files under pub/static are created dynamically and are symlinks on your original files - so they also get the updates

Magento deploys the needed files to pub/static, thats why you find them there. You still have to develop in the theme itself.

Comment: got it to work!! now the new template is showing in the back end, but the CSS and JS fiels are loading. when i run the cmd, php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --- i get the following Compilation from source:
frontend/MyStore/MyAbstract/en_US/css/styles-l.less
variable @button__shadow-active is undefined in file /chroot/home/installs/xxxxxxx/html/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/MyStore/MyAbstract/en_US/css/source/_extends.less in _extends.less on line 37, column 30
35|     }
36|     &:active {
37|         .lib-css(box-shadow, @button__shadow-active);
38|     }
39| }
40| >

Comment: oh ok, can't really help you with that one since I did not look into the less features yet. maybe you should post a new question for this