# magento2 new custom theme no CSS or JS

Tags: magento2, javascript, css

After creating a new theme in `app\design\frontend\` appears in my back end under design.

When I change it to my custom theme, CSS or JS is NOT loading.

I tried running the following command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Deleted `var\cache, var\generation, pub\static\` - but no luck

However my default theme from fresh installations works just fine. I don't think there is any permission issue otherwise my default would not work. is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

you do have at least a valid theme.xml and registration.php in app/design/frontend/YourVendor/yourtheme/ ?

did you try to enable the developer mode? (at the top of the .htaccess in your root dir)

There is also a 'theme' table in your db. You might want to look in it if everything is ok.

Once we had the problem that the type was set to virtual and noone knows why. Be sure it's 0

Comment: i followed: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100691/magento-2-theme: MyStore/MyAbstract/ - i did enable the developer mode. according to my theme table in my DB  "type' is set to 1. i changed to 0. did the following, php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy and remove all the static files clear all the cache, still no luck

Answer (score 0):

When you have removed `pub/static`, you removed the `.htaccess` from `pub/static` should not be deleted .htaccess

Comment: helped you with my answer?